# Which fetch_style do I use with PDO, so I can use the PHP extract() function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, associative-array

I have the following:

```
extract($this->model->findByStudentID(4));
print_r($this->model->findByStudentID(4));
echo "student id: " . $student_id;
```

The `extract()` function gives me `int(0)`.  `print_r()` gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [student_id] => 4 ......
```

When I try to echo the variable $student_id, I get nothing.  No errors, nothing.

```
$row($this->model->findByStudentID(4));
echo $row["student_id"];
```

This above gives me an undefined index.

My query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = :student_id';
        $this->adapter->prepare($sql);
        $place_holders = array(':student_id' => $_student_search);
        $this->adapter->execute($place_holders);
        $results = $this->adapter->fetchAll();

        foreach ($results as $student){
            echo "</br>" . $student["student_id"] . " , " . $student["LAST"] . "</br>";

        } //this works

        extract($results);
        echo $student_id . ' My student ID.';  //undefined variable
```

Finally, this works:

```
 echo $results[0]['student_id'] . ' THIS IS IT';
```

I'm only bringing back a single record, each time, so how do I get `extract()` to work so I can simply have `$student_id` via the `extract()` function?

How can I see what `extract()` has done?
How do I reference my extracted variables, which I thought should have been $student_id, $last, $first, etc.
(I am not using extract() with the request variables, so extract seems valid in this context.)

Comment: Using extract() is a bad practice, because you create global variables and especially when you use `fetchAll()` method

Comment: Usage of `extract()` is only appropriate when you pass variables from controller/presenter to html template.

Answer (score 3):

`extract` returns the number of variables it extracted. So you can't directly see what it's done.

Using it for this purpose is going to create headaches later for exactly that reason: you can't see which variables it has created. When you or someone else comes back to that piece of code later you or they will be using a few choice curse words! You're better off using the array or object options from PDO fetch.

As @bad_boy said in the comments, it's more suited to extracting variables into the scope of a template.

---

A common templating example to demonstrate where it is often used would be something along these lines:

```
ob_start();
extract($myDataForTheTemplate);
include('my-template.phtml');
$templateContents = ob_get_clean();
```

The contents of the `$myDataForTheTemplate` array are made available to the template file included underneath.

Instead of having to use `$myDataForTheTemplate['myValue']`, the template would be able to do:

```
<p><?= $myValue ?></p>
```

Please note that this is just a basic example demonstrating a common use case for `extract`. Most of the time it's unnecessary or would complicate things.

Comment: Can you explain that please?  I don't understand how I extract in the template vs somewhere else.

Comment: @johnny Look at any framework (Controller part), so you'll get the clue instantly

Comment: @johnny I've added some explanation underneath.

Comment: @bcmcfc How did you get the data into $myDataForTheTemplate?

Comment: @johnny I was just demonstrating extract's use case - the data can come from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`extract()` needs an associative array. You are passing it a numerically indexed array so it fails returning `0` since no variables were extracted.  What you are in essence asking it to do is set variables with these names:

```
$0
$1
...
$n (index for your last row of data)
```

These are obviously invalid variable names.

As others have mentioned using `extract()` is generally bad practice, as you are polluting the global namespace and a very non-intuitive manner.  For example, what if the DB schema changed to add a new column.  You could be introducing a new variable name into global scope without anything in your code to show you this.

Comment: What should I use?  A foreach and assign the variables?  Thanks.

Comment: @johnny I would probably use fetchObject and work with the properties in that object like `$student->LAST`, $student->student_id`, etc.  `fetchAll` should IMO be limited to those cases when you know the result set will be multiple records, but a limited number of rows such that it would not be problematic holding the entire result set in memory.  For the case where you are working with a single expected record, it doesn't make much sense at all to use `fetchALL`